# Giving up on Windows

Tags: windows

I have a Toshiba satellite L750D 6 months old, with a now defected windows 7 64 bit SP1 OS, a week ago MS sent 60 auto updates, after the upload it went into auto restart and never recovered, I went through the system but could not get it to recover the only open systen was command prompt, my PC seller tells me it doesn't come under the warranty because it will be a software problem, Toshiba point the finger at the seller, telling me they purchased the warranty, MS failed to answer my problems, so I purchased a MS recovery disc which failed to recover, telling me no operating system could be found, yet I can clearly see the file via command prompt.

Now I feel my only option is to purchase a new OS disk of Windows 7 or give up and join the growing dissatisfied MS users. So my question is.......

With my new computer in it's present state only Command prompt can I upload Ubuntu without having to shell out on the windows disk. However my worry is my files with all my own data and my draft web site I was upgrading for the last month, will i be able to access these or will they be lost.

Comment: I would suggest live cd booting and mounting the NTFS partition to back up your personal data before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I may not be of the best computer knowledge to help, but this sounds similar to what happened with my own laptop. Can you get into Safe Mode at all? Mine could not get into normal windows but I was able to at least save my files using safe mode so I would suggest trying that.

And, you can certainly get Ubuntu installed as long as your laptop is able to turn on (just download it onto an empty disk or USB stick and put it in your laptop before it opens). Though you will lose all your files if you haven't backed them up..

Comment: You still can boot Ubuntu from the CD/DVD (or USB) and use it to recover the files in the NTFS partition. The Ubuntu disk gives you the option 'Try Ubuntu' which won't damage the contents of your  hdd, then you can just move your important files to a flash drive for example.